# Creating A 5x5 empty matrix where all elements are equal to NA, then fill the diagonal with set of characters in R

Tags: r, matrix

Hi how would you create a Matrix in R that displays all values as NA, but fills the diagonals with characters of different lengths that you assign. For example,

```
Hi NA NA NA NA
NA pet NA NA NA
NA NA juice NA NA 
NA NA NA sun NA
NA NA NA NA laugh
```

Answer (score 1):

This is literally in the definition of the `diag` function:

> Extract or replace the diagonal of a matrix, ...

```
m <- matrix(nr=5,nc=5)
diag(m) <- c("Hi","pet","juice","sun","laugh")
m
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]    [,4]  [,5]   
# [1,] "Hi" NA    NA      NA    NA     
# [2,] NA   "pet" NA      NA    NA     
# [3,] NA   NA    "juice" NA    NA     
# [4,] NA   NA    NA      "sun" NA     
# [5,] NA   NA    NA      NA    "laugh"
```